# How to disable titile in AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I need to draw a chart but no title will be shown. I can draw the chart using AChartEngine but can not find any way to disable title. In case I pass a string like this "" for title they show line instead of title. what to do?

Answer (score 1):

renderer.setChartTitle(""); or simply make sure this method is not called at all.

Dan